# How to access a matching sequence in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

The following expression

```
print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)(?:\.(.))*/
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = 'a';
$VAR2 = 'd';
```

Where are `b` and `c`? How to get them?

*Update: Further simplification*

The following expression

```
print Dumper "abcd" =~ /(.)+/
```

captures only the last character:

```
$VAR1 = 'd';
```

How to capture all characters?

*Another update for those who do not believe me that I can neither use the global modifier nor split.*

I would like to capture all digits in the following example.

```
print Dumper "x1234y" =~ /(\d)+/
```

The expression captures just the last digit:

```
$VAR1 = '4';
```

What I want is this:

```
@digits = ();
"x1234y" =~ /^x(:?(\d)(?{push @digits, $^N}))+y$/;
print Dumper @digits;
```

Which captures all digits:

```
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '2';
$VAR3 = '3';
$VAR4 = '4';
```

The Perl documentation marks the code embedding feature with the following warning:

> Using this feature safely requires that you understand its limitations.

And because I am not sure, whether I understand the limitations, I though there might be a simpler way to get the same. That is what this question is about.

Comment: try `print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)(?=\.|$)/`

Comment: `(?:\.(.))*` would match all the characters which follows `a` and captures only the last character `d`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Have you tried it yourself? `print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)(?=\.|$)/` prints just `a`.

Comment: `print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)(?=\.|$)/g`

Answer (score 1):

They're not there because you have a `*` outside your capture group, and you're not repeating the pattern.

Thus what happens in the regex engine is:

```
Compiling REx "(.)(?:\.(.))*"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   REG_ANY (4)
   4: CLOSE1 (6)
   6: CURLYX[1] {0,32767} (16)
   8:   EXACT <.> (10)
  10:   OPEN2 (12)
  12:     REG_ANY (13)
  13:   CLOSE2 (15)
  15: WHILEM[1/1] (0)
  16: NOTHING (17)
  17: END (0)
minlen 1 
Matching REx "(.)(?:\.(.))*" against "a.b.c.d"
   0 <> <a.b.c.d>            |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <a.b.c.d>            |  3:REG_ANY(4)
   1 <a> <.b.c.d>            |  4:CLOSE1(6)
   1 <a> <.b.c.d>            |  6:CURLYX[1] {0,32767}(16)
   1 <a> <.b.c.d>            | 15:  WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..32767
   1 <a> <.b.c.d>            |  8:    EXACT <.>(10)
   2 <a.> <b.c.d>            | 10:    OPEN2(12)
   2 <a.> <b.c.d>            | 12:    REG_ANY(13)
   3 <a.b> <.c.d>            | 13:    CLOSE2(15)
   3 <a.b> <.c.d>            | 15:    WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                      whilem: matched 1 out of 0..32767
   3 <a.b> <.c.d>            |  8:      EXACT <.>(10)
   4 <a.b.> <c.d>            | 10:      OPEN2(12)
   4 <a.b.> <c.d>            | 12:      REG_ANY(13)
   5 <a.b.c> <.d>            | 13:      CLOSE2(15)
   5 <a.b.c> <.d>            | 15:      WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                        whilem: matched 2 out of 0..32767
   5 <a.b.c> <.d>            |  8:        EXACT <.>(10)
   6 <a.b.c.> <d>            | 10:        OPEN2(12)
   6 <a.b.c.> <d>            | 12:        REG_ANY(13)
   7 <a.b.c.d> <>            | 13:        CLOSE2(15)
   7 <a.b.c.d> <>            | 15:        WHILEM[1/1](0)
                                          whilem: matched 3 out of 0..32767
   7 <a.b.c.d> <>            |  8:          EXACT <.>(10)
                                            failed...
                                          whilem: failed, trying continuation...
   7 <a.b.c.d> <>            | 16:          NOTHING(17)
   7 <a.b.c.d> <>            | 17:          END(0)
Match successful!
```

Your non capturing bracket `(?:` is redundant as well.

How about:

```
print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)\.(.)/g;
```

Which prints:

```
$VAR1 = 'a';
$VAR2 = 'b';
$VAR3 = 'c';
$VAR4 = 'd';
```

Or alternatively (it wasn't entirely clear what you were seeking):

```
print Dumper "a.b.c.d" =~ /(.)\.(.+)/;


$VAR1 = 'a';
$VAR2 = 'b.c.d';
```

> Update: Further simplification

```
print Dumper "abcd" =~ /(.)+/
```

> How to capture all characters?

Again - the problem is - you're capturing a single character in your brackets, and then using `+` to alter how much of the pattern is 'consumed'. So you will only ever get a single character here, because you told it to.

If you want all of them, put the plus *inside* the brackets and you will get a single scalar.

```
print Dumper "abcd" =~ /(.+)/;
```

If you want *each* of them as separate elements:

```
print Dumper "abcd" =~ /(.)/g;
```

Repeat the capture operation. Or use `split`:

```
print Dumper split //, "abcd";
```

Edit: Following your last edit:

```
"x1234y" =~ /^x(:?(\d)(?{push @digits, $^N}))+y$/;
```

This still doesn't illustrate the the question you're asking properly, because this works:

```
my @digits = "x1234y" =~ m/(\d)/g; 
print Dumper \@digits;
```

And if it didn't, then this works:

```
my @digits = split ( //, "x1234y" =~ s/\D//rg  );
```

Or this:

```
my @digits = grep { /\d/ } split //, "x1234y";
```

Comment: I think the question is about how (if possible) access all captured texts from the second capturing group (as in .NET `CaptureCollection`).

Comment: I do not think that the non capturing parenthesis is redundant, because I do not want the dots.

Comment: You don't need the parens at all though. For this job `split /\./` is probably a better tool.

Comment: The `g` modifier does what I tried to achieve. But I can not use it, because the expression is part of a bigger one and it would be false to make the whole expression global.

Comment: @Sobrique I do not want to split 4 characters separated by dots. This is just a simplification to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Complicated single regex solutions to parsing are - IMO - rarely the right answer to anything. Breaking down the problem means it's easier to test, validated and maintain.

Comment: @ceving Presenting a "simplified" case is good in so many realms of knowledge... I don't think that applies to regex. especially when you are not intimately familiar with all the subtleties of regex, trying to simplify the pattern will almost universally leave out or alter some detail that is more or less vital to the actual solution sought. Provide the source, show what should be matched, and ideally show what is close but should not be matched. That's pretty much it until there are clarifying questions to answer.

Comment: @Sobrique - I think you've got a typo with your global switch(?)

Comment: Well spotted, yes. I'll probably stick with my assertion - if you have a regex that needs simplifying, then the problem is you're trying to do too much with a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to get a single capture group inside a repetition operator to produce multiple output strings. And you still haven't shown an example that isn't handled perfectly well by a simple capture of the whole sequence and then split afterward.

The `(?{...})` solution isn't bad, especially in your example where the string is anchored at both ends, so there's no chance of it succeeding with any backtracking.

To work in a more general case, you should initialize the array just before the repetition starts, so you don't get leftovers from partial matches, like this:

```
@digits=();
"x8w x9z x1234y" =~ /x(?:(\d)(?{push @digits, $^N}))+y/;
# bad, @digits=(8,9,1,2,3,4)

"x88w x9z x1234y" =~ /x(?{@digits=()})(?:(\d)(?{push @digits, $^N}))+y/;
# better, @digits=(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: In the context I am using the regexp the whole expression must match, because it performs a validation. It is not sufficient to pick just some matches and ignore the rest. The expression must not capture anything, if the the surrounding parts do not match. It might be possible to do two steps: first match all and afterwards split. But that performs the matching twice and copies the data twice. And it would be nice to avoid that.